# MOSFET burns - 220V inverter for induction motor speed control using Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, mosfet-driver, induction-motor

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have been working for quite some time on my project to control the speed of a 220 V, 60 Hz, 0.35 A induction motor (domestic fan). I use an Arduino to generate 60 Hz with a switching frequency of 10 kHz. When I try my circuit with a 20 V motor, it works well and I can even vary the frequency.

But once I connect to 220 V the MOSFETs suddenly burn (explode) and the gate driver burns too. I came to understand that I don't have much knowledge of what is going on here.

Components used:

- OPTO-ISOLATOR - 4N35
- MOSFET - IRF830
- GATE DRIVER - IR2113
- BOOTSTRAP CAP (MLCC) - 47 μF
- BOOTSTRAP DIODE - SCHOTTKY DIODE (400 V)

I have tried to achieve deadtime too, but still the same issue. I have converted AC to DC using a bridge rectifier, inductor (15 mH, 4 A), and DC link, (400 V, 2200 uF), then I fed this to my inverter.

Here is my attached inverter circuit design:
NOTE: the Proteus design is my system overview, I couldn't simulate it there as I had trouble during simulation, actual components I have mentioned above.

Comment: Realize that **depending on the type of motor that is used in the fan** it might be **very complex** to regulate it's speed. That 20 V motor is very likely a DC motor while the fan motor is likely an AC motor. Those motor types are **very different**. I would also highly **discourage** messing with 220 V when you have little idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you  @Bimpelrekkie, I have studied how I can achieve this, then I had to conduct research, that's the reason I'm working on it.  I wish to learn this too. I believe it can be a good step for me even though it is dangerous, haha.

Comment: .35A, it is a domestic fan. just for air circulation, so no heavy load on it, 75Watts.

Comment: Using a gate driver with ~25ns rise/fall times on a perfboard like that is asking for problems. Do you have a scope? It's probably ringing like crazy.

Comment: Your post requires additional details as noted by the comments above.

Comment: well, yes. I have a scope. when I probe high side or low side output, I just see the spwm signals generated, so I couldn't think of this, Thank you for your consideration, May I know what kind of gate drivers would be necessary, I switch at 100ns maybe 25ns is so slow.

Comment: May I know what kind of details? @Syed? Thank you.

Comment: Your schematic indicates no isolation between Arduino and mains side. And where does the 15V come from? The U2 VS and HO are incorrectly connected to Q1, right? And you do realize the node that has the GND symbol will vary between 0V and -310V as per the incoming mains sine wave?

Comment: Anything 25 ns on a breadboard without groundplane is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: What value are the bootstrap caps, 47n or 47u? They seem badly soldered, cold joints. The path from gate driver to the gate shall be as short as possible, while you have very long resistor and diode legs instead. Is the PWM duty time limited? The bootstrap won't work with 100% DT.

Comment: @Justme, Thank you. So Arduino and mains are separated by optocoupler 4n35, and for U2 Vs and Ho i schematically connected wrong. Should be connected as others.

Comment: What do you mean the ground will vary by incoming sine wave? Isn’t ground usually approximately 0v? Because there are two low side mosfets which turns on alternatively and connect the load to ground.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, 47uF. I will consider that. Good connection of boot cap and gate resistor distance. But wont i have to place the mosfets a bit far from gate drive? Because i may have to cover mosfets with heatsink.

Comment: You said you have 400V coming from a bridge rectifier. If you simply take in mains live and neutral and rectify them, you do have 400V over the capacitor, but capacitor negative lead will not be 0V in respect to earth ground so it is not safe to touch it or connect scope ground lead to it. Please make sure you know what you are doing if you are making circuits live with mains voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your saying, coming out of bridge rectifier is around 311V since i rectify 220V, my capacitor rated volts is 400V. I’m also aware that the scope ground is connected with the main so i dont connect scope ground in my system.

Comment: What may be something else i’m missing, the thing cause the mosfets and gate driver to burn everytime? At first i thought of deadtime, i have worked on that in software but still two mosfet burn at a time with the drive.

Comment: At first, was two mosfets, high side and low side of same gate drive, so i thought of deadband (shoot through) now is two mosfet high side and low side of different gate drive, that means the two that have motor in the middle.

Comment: Have you looked at the waveforms out of the optoisolators? You haven't linked to any datasheets but I have a vague memory of 4N35s being unbelievably slow.

Comment: yes, 4n35 is slow in turning off, therefore I have pulled the base of the transistor to the emitter to enhance turn off, in that way I was able to achieve a good output at optoisolator level, I have confirmed it with the scope too.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately see a problem. Gate drive for Q1 from pin 7 of U2, is shorted to Q1 source! Q1 source should connect to pin 5 of U2, and the gate of Q1 should drive from pin 7.

I suggest review your design for similar mistakes as a first step.

Comment: (I can see the short in the schematic. can you pinpoint column&row designations if it is in the PCB's solder side, too?) How do you explain *with a 20 V motor, it works well*?

Comment: If your schematic and layout do not match that is another problem. I cannot follow that breadboard.

Comment: As for why it is failing at high voltage, there are many possible problems. Ringing, miller effect, lack of output filtering (self-capacitance of the motor will be significant at switching frequency), inductive load of the motor (reactive power will be returned to the supply), modulation depth too high so your bootstraps stop working, lack of isolation (clearance distance on PCB) between nodes at different voltages... Just a few. Diagnostics require, differential voltage probes, DSO/CRO, current probe, limited current DC supply, resistive test load.